# Await for a variable to change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an observable that needs to be executed before the next instruction

```typescript
export class MyExample implements OnInit {
    flag;

    constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

    myFunc() {
        flag = 0;
        this.myService.subscribe(data => {
            this.consumeData(data);
            this.flag = 1;
        });
    }
}
```

Instructions inside the `subscribe()` may take few seconds to be ready. I need to transform `init()` function to `async init()`. I added a `flag` that works as an indicator of success but I couldn't find a way to combine an Observable with an async function (or maybe just a promise).

In my Component I want to call `init()` this way:

```typescript
this.myFunc().then(() => console.log('ok'));
```

Comment: `async` works with `Promise`. The keyword `async` makes it implicit that such method returns a `Promise` and allows you to use `await` on methods returning a `Promise`. Unluckily, it doesn't have much to do with `Observables`. Is there any reason for using an observable here? You may just want to do: `return this.myService.subscribe(data => {
    this.consumeData(data);
    this.flag = 1;
}).toPromise();`.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm aware of that. I'm just talking about syntax

Comment: no probs, it seemed like you thought they were two distinct things - comment removed

Comment: What is init() ? Are you talking about ngOnInit(), which is not implemented in your snippet ?

Comment: @jo_va I edited the post. It's not an `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to treat an observable like a promise, then the simplest thing would be `await this.myService.toPromise()`.

Answer (score 0):

An Observable is kind of a stream of data... If you only have one value coming out of the observable, consider using

```
return this.myService.
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(...)
```

this way the observable will also be unsubscribed automatically.

you can also call `toPromise()` instead of `subscribe(...)` and use the result as a promise

```
return this.myService.
  .pipe(take(1))
  .toPromise().then(...)
```

you can then use `await` together with it

Comment: In my case, the service is a bluetooth low energy (BLE). I need to connect to the service and then start notifications. So It's not a single value. to connect to a peripheral, the device takes like 3 seconds. The start notification is an observable too. It's nested inside the connect observable. What I need to do is to make sure that the device is connected and subscribe notifications then let the application run normally.

Answer (score 0):

Observable can be easily converted to promises by using the `toPromise()` operator.

```
async myFunc() {
    return this.myService.doSomething().pipe(
         tap(data => this.consumeData(data)) 
    ).toPromise();
}
```